# Bash replace string where specific condition is true

Tags: bash, shell, replace, sed

I am trying to replace a string where a specific condition is true in the same line

I have a file with some lines. I to replace a word (word1) with another (word2) in every line that starts with another word (word3)

For example:

```
foo moo see
kaa haa qee
foo dee see
uuu ooo rrr
foo dee laa
```

I want to replace the word "see" with "raa" in every line which begins with "foo". So doing that will result in the lines being like:

```
foo moo raa
kaa haa qee
foo dee raa
uuu ooo rrr
foo dee laa
```

I was told that I can use sed to do that but I didn't figure out how to do that.

Please help! (with sed only)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is very basic `sed`:

```
$ sed '/^foo/s/see/raa/g' file
foo moo raa
kaa haa qee
foo dee raa
uuu ooo rrr
foo dee laa
```

#### Explanation

- `sed 's/something/replacement/g'` replaces `something` strings with `replacement`. The `g` indicates that it is to be done every time it can.
- Adding `/^foo/` makes it just take into consideration the lines starting with `foo`.
- If you want the file to be edited in place, that is, to have the file content updated with the substitution, add `-i`: `sed -i.bak '/^foo/s/see/raa/g' file`. `file.bak` will contain the previous file.

---

#### Update

> How to use variables instead of foo, see, raa ? –  Khaleal

Like this and with double quotes:

```
$ d="foo"
$ e="see"
$ sed "/^$d/s/$e/raa/g" file
foo moo raa
kaa haa qee
foo dee raa
uuu ooo rrr
foo dee laa
```

and so on.

Comment: How to use variables instead of foo, see, raa ?

Comment: See my updated answer, @Khaleal If it's done, remember you can accept the answer.

Comment: just be carefull with special char in word like . * \ & ? + that have sed meaning in s. Your sample does not show any of them but this is maybe not the case in all your file

Answer (score 4):

I know its asked for `sed`, but posting an `awk` for other to read, if they like.

```
awk '/^foo/ {sub(/see/,"raa")}1' file
```