# Bash finding when specific condition is true using sed with different delimiter

Tags: bash, shell, sed, replace

Similar to what [Bash replace string where specific condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664446/bash-replace-string-where-specific-condition-is-true) asked I want to replace part of a line based on a prior condition but my delimiter must be different because part of what I am replacing includes /. The condition is also not in the first column but instead the second.

For example my data includes:

```
Location Ref Alt GT1 GT2
1_100004338 T C 0/0 0/0
1_100004339 C T 0/0 0/1
1_100004343 A G 1/1 0/0
```

If I want to base it on if I have a C in Ref (column 2) and replace all occurrences of 0/0 with 2:

```
Location Ref Alt GT1 GT2
1_100004338 T C 0/0 0/0
1_100004339 C T 2 0/1
1_100004343 A G 1/1 0/0
```

I have tried the following input

```
sed "+^"C"+s+"0/0"+"2"+g" file
```

and get the error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `^'
```

I am not sure if it would have even gave me what I wanted if it worked though as C is in the second column and not the beginning of the line. I have tried using other ways like awk BEGIN which is way to slow for how big my file is.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only modify the delimiter with the `s` command. When using a regexp for matching the line is has to use `/` delimiters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed ):

```
sed '/^\S\+ C /s#0/0#2#g' file
```

If the second column is `C` replace all occurrences of `0/0` with `2`.

---

or if you prefer:

```
sed -E '/^\S+\s+C\s+/s#0/0#2#g' file
```

Comment: Nice. I'd replace the space in the regular expression with `\s+`, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` would be more suitable for this.

```
$ awk '$2=="C" {$4=2}1' input_file
Location Ref Alt GT1 GT2
1_100004338 T C 0/0 0/0
1_100004339 C T 2 0/1
1_100004343 A G 1/1 0/0
```

If `$2` column 2 string is C, then `$4` column 4 equals 2.

If `sed` is a must, you can try this.

```
$ sed '/[^ ]* C [A-Z]/ {s|0/0|2|}' input_file
Location Ref Alt GT1 GT2
1_100004338 T C 0/0 0/0
1_100004339 C T 2 0/1
1_100004343 A G 1/1 0/0
```